# Safari - how to see web developer tools like DOM inspector?

Tags: safari, web-inspector

In on Yosemite using Safari.

How can I "inspect element"

I've looked through all the preferences and don't see any way to turn on developer tools so I can do inspect element (if that is even possible with them).

Answer (score 1):

Found it - a bit hidden its at the bottom of preferences - advanced, i.e.

"Show Develop menu in menu bar"

[image]